# In Perl, how can I do a non-blocking system call?

Tags: perl

In Perl, without using the `Thread` library, what is the simplest way to spawn off a system call so that it is non-blocking?  Can you do this while avoiding `fork()` as well?

EDIT
Clarification.  I want to avoid an explicit and messy call to fork.

Comment: Fork is the idiom of the OS for processes--there is no reason to avoid forking on nix systems. But there are always reasons to encapsulate and homogenize access points.

Comment: What is messy about fork, and why do you want to avoid an explicit one?

Comment: Can you show me a relatively simple one-line system call using fork()?  Please do, because I'm not very good at Perl.  I've never used fork() in Perl, but the examples I found seemed pretty complicated.  The motivation for my question is I want to move and then delete a large directory ( which I don't care if it fails sporadically). The directory can take minutes to delete ( it's on NFS ) and I want to reduce build time.  After I remove the directory , I need to re-use/recreate the directory in a build flow. Thus, I want the simplest fire-and-forget method to move and delete this directory.

Comment: Is it entirely necessary for the same script to delete the directory? You could move it to another directory that periodically gets cleaned out by a cron, or any variation on that theme.

Comment: Just learn how to fork. Then you'll know. I'm not sure why you think it is messy.

Comment: @RossRogers I know it's an old question, but maybe next seekers will find this helpfull, just use `system("START " . $cmd);`

Comment: There is no `START` on Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
system('my_command_which_will_not_block &');
```

As Chris Kloberdanz points out, this will call fork() implicitly -- there's really no other way for perl to do it; especially if you want the perl interpreter to continue running while the command executes.

The `&` character in the command is a shell meta-character -- perl sees this and passes the argument to `system()` to the shell (usually bash) for execution, rather than running it directly with an `execv()` call. `&` tells bash to fork again, run the command in the background, and exit immediately, returning control to perl while the command continues to execute.

Comment: Doesn't system implicitly use fork() though?

Comment: Clarification. I want to avoid an explicit and messy call to fork.

Comment: **Sigh** I *guess* a "non-blocking system call" *could* mean that.

Comment: Sinan: Yeah, I took "system call" to mean "perl system() call", rather than an OS kernel system call -- lucky guess on my part, I suppose :)

Comment: sry for the confusion. Thanks all.

Comment: The problem in your wording: you want a non-blocking `system()` call, which is not at all the same as a non-blocking system call. (A system call calls an OS primitive, whereas `system()` invokes an executable or executes a shell command line - different level.)

Answer (score 4):

The post above says "there's no other way for perl to do it", which is not true.

Since you mentioned file deletion, take a look at [IO::AIO](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::AIO).  This performs the system calls in another thread (POSIX thread, not Perl pseudothread); you schedule the request with `aio_rmtree` and when that's done, the module will call a function in your program.  In the mean time, your program can do anything else it wants to.

Doing things in another POSIX thread is actually a generally useful technique.  (A special hacked version of) Coro uses it to preempt coroutines (time slicing), and EV::Loop::Async uses it to deliver event notifications even when Perl is doing something other than waiting for events.